# Tester Class Constructor Error

Tags: java

This is the homework question I have to answer: Implement a class `SodaCan` whose constructor receives the height and diameter or the soda can. Supply methods `getVolume` and `getSurfaceArea`. Supply a `SodaCanTester` class that tests your class.

This is the code I have for the `SodaCan` class.

```
public class SodaCan
{
    private double Height;
    private double Radius;

    public SodaCan(double h, double d) {
        Height = h;
        Radius = d/2;
    }

    public double getVolume()
    {
        return Math.PI * Height * Math.pow(Radius, 2);
    }

    public double getSurfaceArea()
    {
        return (2 * Math.PI * Radius * Height) + 
        (2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(Radius, 2));
    }   
}
```

This is the code I have for the `SodaCanTester` class.

```
public class SodaCanTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       SodaCan cylinder = new SodaCan();
       cylinder.enterHeight(5);
       cylinder.enterRadius(8);
       System.out.println("Volume: " + getVolume());
       System.out.println("Expected Volume: 1005.31");
       System.out.println("Surface Area: " + getSurfaceArea());
       System.out.println("Expected Surface Area: 653.45");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the tester class, I get an error with the constructor:

```
SodaCan cylinder = new SodaCan();
```

That says:

> "constructor SodaCan in class SodaCan cannot be applied to given types".

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you have have args constructor in your class `SodaCan`

```
public SodaCan(double h, double d) {
    Height = h;
    Radius = d/2;
}
```

You need to ***explicitly*** declare no-arg constructor, if you want to make the below code work

```
SodaCan cylinder = new SodaCan();
```

***Edited==***

Your code should look like this

```
public SodaCan(double h, double d) {
    Height = h;
    Radius = d/2;
}

public SodaCan(){}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, so correct me if I'm wrong.  Would the code have to look like this? `public SodaCan() {
                Height = h;
                Radius = d/2;
        }` @Ravi

Comment: @NikkiAgarwal just append no-arg constructor in `SodaCan` class

Comment: Add a second constructor or use the one you've built

Comment: @NikkiAgarwal just append no-arg constructor in `SodaCan` class.

Comment: @Ravi @DanielJipa I added `public SodaCan(){}` right after  `private double Radius` in  the `SodaCan` class. Now, I'm receiving an error that says _cannot find symbol_ for `enterHeight()`, `enterRadius()`, `getVolume()`, and `"getSurfaceArea"`. So, I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're saying right.

Comment: @NikkiAgarwal You didn’t define those methods. You sort of seem to be typing at random-maybe taking a step back and looking at compilable Java code might be a good idea?

Comment: @Ravi Thank you so much! I understand it now!!

Comment: @DaveNewton I also see that I seem to be struggling with constructors, so I will make sure to do that! Thank you for the advice!